# How upgrade devise 2.1.2 to devise 3.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, upgrade

I want to upgrade my current devise from 2.1.2 to 3.2.2
I added the secret_key to the initialiser so the rails server starts fine.
But when I try to login I can't. Examining the logs didn't make me any smarter.
I just get a 401 Unauthorized exception in the Rails log.

Can anybody give direction how to upgrade? Or how I could debug this a little bit better?

Comment: if you create a new user can that user login?

Comment: What does the server log say?

Comment: I am having the same issue. New users can login fine, but old users cannot. One solution i found was to use the "forgot password" link to reset the password. This fixes the issue, but users shouldn't have to reset their password, so if anyone finds anything, please let us know!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check your sign in field. if you follow devise guide (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address), your sign in field should be "login", not "email"